# Image Compression (JPEG) - Show the Effect of Number of Coefficients on Quality

Tags: matlab, image-processing, homework, image-compression

write an m-file that will take the"cameraman" and produce a image quality or difference matrix for spectral selection method.The image properties are a sfollowings:
For spectral selection:
image1:DC coefficiant only
Image 2:first A/2 coefficiant including DC,where is the number of coefficiants prior to the EOB symbol.
All non-zero(A) coefficients including DC

This is my homework.I do not want to give me the ecaxt answer,but please can u give me any idea or link where might be related and helpful in finding the answer.
sound really tough to me.
cheers

Comment: At least format the question correctly first.

Comment: What have you tried so far? No one on this site will help you unless you've shown some effort.